# HTTP 403 forbidden Token not found ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to add a like on click while calling the API.
I have added a token but still in error is shows Forbidden no token provided. whereas it works fine in postman.
can't understand why isn't it working.

`<ion-icon name="heart" class="icons" (click)="addLike(post._id)"></ion-icon>`

home.module.ts

```
    addLike(postId) {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        token = token.substring(1, token.length-1);

        this.api.likePost(token, postId).then((res) => {
            console.log("Post like API call complete");
            console.log(res);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Error in API");
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

api.service.ts

```
    async likePost(token, postId) {
        console.log("post ID "+postId);
        console.log("token "+token);

        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'x-access-token': token,
        });
        let options = {
            headers: headers
        }
        return await (this.http.put(environment.endpoint + "/api/v1/like-post/"+postId, options)).toPromise();
    }
```

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k32VZ.png)

Comment: check your network tab, click on the url, and check the header tab to see the content of x-access-token

Comment: @akisoft It doesn't show it in the header tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a mistake in api.service.ts

In this.http.put the 2nd parameter is data and 3rd is options. This is the reason why it is not reading the header.

```
async likePost(token, postId) {
    console.log("post ID "+postId);
    console.log("token "+token);

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'x-access-token': token,
    });
    let options = {
        headers: headers
    }
    return await (this.http.put(environment.endpoint + "/api/v1/like-post/"+postId, options)).toPromise();
}
```